# Android Configuring For multiple Screen Densities

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size, screen-density

I am having trouble configuring my Android application for another screen density. Currently, my app runs on HDPI (1.5) screens and I am trying to get the dimensions of my pngs and my values in my dimension.xml to be compatible with XHDPI (2.0) screens.

For example, my background png is currently 1280px x 800px and it works well with my HDPI (1.5) screen. I assumed this would mean that I would need a 1280 * (4/3) = 1706.67px by 800 * (4/3) = 1066.67px dimension png. This did not show the same as my current tablet.

Also, my screens are almost exactly the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- LDPI = 0.75x
- MDPI = ORIGINAL
- HDPI = 1.5x

If you have an image 1000X1000 (pixels) you have to create the following versions of the image:

- LDPI = 750x750
- LMDPI = 1000X1000 (THE ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE)
- MDPI = 1500X15000

Except, in @dimension, HAS NOT put some values "dp" or "sp" and then used them in the style of the image.

Answer (score 0):

[never use px in xml. It just need two kinds of pictures,one is xxhdpi,other one is xxxhdpi.If you need a xxxhdpi picture but drop it in xxhdpi's folder.That will influence your memory.So use xxhdpi and xxxhdpi is enough.But you need use dp or match_parent or weight to profile you png's size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuuOA.png)

Comment: If I use the same dimensions for each screen in my XML my layouts run off the page on my XHDPI screen compared to my HDPI screen

Comment: Yes,it is.DP has nothing to do with screen pixels.It means  that a 50 dp png on XHDPI is the same size on HDPI. So, it will too big shown on HDPI. There are three rules following:    1. show a small pic that it will not influence the typography(like Relativelayout)：just use dp.    2. show a pic which will influence the typography( like Linearlayout): use weight will be good. 3. show a big pic use persent(exe: 50% width and 50%height ):This will be complex,you should use match_parent or make four kinds of values folders,each folder  saves lay_x.xml and lay_y.xml to  profile different dp.